# Add milliseconds to Date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to resolve very simple case :) - need to add milliseconds to Date in Pandas.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['date_start_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DATE']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['QTR_HR_START']/1000)
```

and sure I got an error:

> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\timedeltas.py",
>   line 97, in _coerce_scalar_to_timedelta_type
>       return tslib.convert_to_timedelta(r,unit)   File "tslib.pyx", line 1283, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_timedelta (pandas\tslib.c:22255)
>   File "tslib.pyx", line 1338, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_timedelta64
>   (pandas\tslib.c:22901) ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar:

What is correct way to do it?

```
   Unnamed: 0       DATE  QTR_HR_START  QTR_HR_END  PERIOD_LENGTH  
0           1 2013-01-01      21600000    22499000         899000   
1           2 2013-01-01      22500000    23399000         899000   
2           3 2013-01-01      23400000    24299000         899000   
3           4 2013-01-01      23400000    24299000         899000   
4           5 2013-01-01      24300000    25199000         899000   
5           6 2013-01-01      25200000    26099000         899000   
6           7 2013-01-01      25200000    26099000         899000
```

Comment: What are some of the values in `df['QTR_HR_START']` ? Can you show example data?

Comment: can you simply do `print(df.head(10))` and copy paste that result in the question

Comment: unable to reproduce,  code runs fine and returns `15706 days 00:00:00.000021, 15706 days 00:00:00.000022...`

Comment: Thank you all, but do you have any ideas why I am getting the error?